# Evaluating surface integral, not sure where I'm going wrong?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the surface integral 
$\iint_S (x^2z + y^2z)dS$, where S is the hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 =4, z\geq0$.

To start, I parametrize S through spherical coordinates to end up with

$r(\phi, \theta) = 
4sin(\phi)cos(\theta)i+4sin(\phi)sin(\theta)k+4cos(\phi)$

Evaluating the cross product between $r_\phi$ and $r_\theta$ results in the expression $4sin(\phi)$. This then results in the integral

$\int\int z(x^2+y^2)\cdot4sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta$

which can be rewritten as

$32\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} sin^3(\phi)cos(\theta) d\phi d\theta$.

This, however, ends up evaluating to $0$ (as the inner integral evaluates to $\frac{cos^3(x)}{3} - cos(x)|_{0}^{\pi/2} = \frac{2}{3}$, which then leads to the integral of

$32\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{2}{3}cos(\theta)d\theta$

which evaluates to $0$. Does anyone know where/if I'm going wrong?

Comment: Two small typos/errors: the equation for the hemisphere should be squares and the coefficients for the parameterization should be $2$. However the real error comes when you get the integral purely in terms of your parameterization variables. Notice that in the step immediately before, the integrand is clearly always nonnegative. But $\sin^3(\phi)\cos(\theta)$ is negative on parts of the hemisphere. Do you see the mistake?

Comment: $x^3+y^3+z^3=4,z\ge0$ is not hemisphere. Perhaps you mean $x^2+y^2+z^2=4,z\ge0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List below all the pieces in the surface integral,
$$z=r\cos\phi\\
x^2+y^2=r^2\sin^2\phi\\
dS=r^2 \sin\phi d\phi d\theta
$$
Plug them into the integral,
$$ \iint_S z(x^2 + y^2)dS = r^5\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\phi \sin^3\phi d\phi \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta$$
which does not integrate to zero.

The problem is that the term $\cos\theta$ in your integral should be $\cos\phi$, which stems from $z=2\cos\phi$.